# solr sorting in OR query

Tags: solr, lucene, solrj

Is it posible sort results in OR query.

```
skills=java,php,mongodb,scala
```

So query will be `q=skills:java OR php OR scala` Is it posible to sort results like if all skills(java,php,mongodb,scala) match then show on top.(top to bottom) and single skill matching at bottom.

Comment: Generally, the *default* sort (that is, by score) will do that.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that correct syntax should be:

```
q=skills:(java OR php OR scala)
```

Anyway, it's not clear what kind of sort you're looking for. 
As @femtoRgon states, given that the default sort is by score, more relevant results comes first.

If you want understand why a document appears first you can enable debug and explain.
Add `debugQuery=true&indent=true&debug.explain.structured=true` to your search url and examine the results.

There is also an useful [Google Chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/solr-query-debugger/gmpkeiamnmccifccnbfljffkcnacmmdl) to see Solr Query explain and debug in a clear manner.